# How Do I create history table that allows me to retrieve the times when a row active by year & month?

Tags: sql-server, dimensional-modeling, slowly-changing-dimension

I want to be able to retrieve the in-between months when a client was active but from a historical table.

Table: DimensionEpisode

| episode_id | client_id | episode_status | discharge_date | admission_date | program_id | length_of_stay | subprogram | ...other attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 61362 | CLOSED | 2018-09-06T00:00:00 | 2014-10-01T00:00:00 | 72 | 1436 | Union PC | ... |
| 64 | 61343 | OPEN | 2019-03-15T00:00:00 | 2015-05-20T00:00:00 | 80 | 1000 | Rehab | ... |
| 65 | 61344 | OPEN | 2020-01-10T00:00:00 | 2018-11-12T00:00:00 | 65 | 750 | Psychiatry | ... |
| 66 | 61345 | CLOSED | 2021-07-02T00:00:00 | 2019-09-28T00:00:00 | 72 | 1250 | Union PC | ... |

Comment: "*when a client was active*" - Means when `episode_status` is `OPEN`? Is the `admission_date` your start date and `discharge_date` your end date for the date range?

Comment: @J.D. yes, correct to both.

Comment: You are saying you don't want a query for this, but a way to populate a history table with the desired data upon inserting an OPEN record?

Comment: A view with a calculated field for the number of months rather than introduce 
complexity and overhead onto the DBMS. Is there something I am missing?